# Websockets, Apache/wamp and PHP

Tags: websocket, phpwebsocket

I am quite new to websockets. I googled and grabbed some example code and none of them is working. All shows disconnected message despite of strictly following the tutorial rules.

I am testing from chrome, wamp and PHP 5.3.13 (php_socket is also active) on localhost, windows 7 ultimate(32bit).

What I want to ask is, do I need to configure my server to support websokets. If not what is the reason of not running it as intended?

Any kind of help is heartily welcomed! 
thanks

Comment: What tutorials did you follow? Are you trying to use WebSockets via a php script running via Apache? Or via another apache module?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you have search through StackOverflow as this question, and similar ones, have been asked quite a few times e.g.

- [Is native PHP support for Web Sockets available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203443/is-native-php-support-for-web-sockets-available)
- [PHP server and websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739733/php-server-and-websockets)
- [Websockets & PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220501/websockets-php)
- [How Can a LAMP Guy Easily Implement WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853410/how-can-a-lamp-guy-easily-implement-websockets)